# How to write IIS rewrite rule to redirect request to different server?

Tags: url-rewriting, iis-7.5, url-rewrite-module

I have my main website running at a hosting company with IIS 7.5 at http://example.com

I'm setting up a WordPress blog at the same hosting company on a Linux, Apache, PHP machine.

When a user types in "http://example.com/blog" I want to redirect the request to the WordPress site.

To the end user they wouldn't know the blog content is being served up from a different server.

What is the specific  IIS rewrite rule needed to do this?

Answer (score 0):

```
       <rewrite>  
          <rules>
            <rule name="Redirect" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url=".*" />
                <conditions>
                    <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^www.mysite1.com$" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Redirect" url="www.mysite2.com" />
            </rule>
        </rules>
    </rewrite>
```